# How can I make Visual Studio update namespaces when I move classes?

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, refactoring, directory

I remember that when I worked with Java tools, I could easily reorganise classes and packages by dragging and dropping them in the IDE. This would automatically update namespaces to match the new file system structure.

In the .NET world, I believe the .NET languages' specifications don't require namespaces to match folder structure. However, I would still like to be able to move class files, or even namespaces, around, and have Visual Studio automatically update the namespaces correspondingly.

How can I achieve this? I'm more interested in a Visual Studio 2010 solution, but I still consider answers for other versions acceptable.

Comment: This just doesn't exist, best to stop assuming it makes *any* attempt at acting like a Java IDE.  You can write a macro or add-in if you really want it.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not assuming it acts like a Java IDE; I'm asking how to achieve this functionality. I consider this a common C#/.NET refactoring.

Comment: Nothing is built in, you have to use Resharper to get this functionality.  It is really disappointing that they don't have something like this out of the box.  How hard would it be to add an option "move namespace with class moves"?